# Find the maximum value of the solid of revolution of the function $f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{e^x}{x}}$.

Tags: calculus, integration

I am given the function:

$$f:[-1, 2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad f(x) = \sqrt{\dfrac{e^x}{x}}$$

and I have to find the maximum value of the solid of revolution around the $Ox$ axis of the function $f$.

I am not sure I understand the statement. I thought that since the volume is always positive and considering a larger domain of the function for the volume of the solid of revolution would result in a larger volume, the maximum volume would be achieved by considering the whole domain of the function, namely $[-1, 2]$. So I tried to find:

$$V = \pi \int_{-1}^2 f^2(x) dx = \pi \int_{-1}^2 \dfrac{e^x}{x} dx$$

But I got stuck, I can't find that integral. After looking a bit on the internet I found that this is actually a really complicated integral, which led me to believe that my approach to this problem is wrong, it should be something that is not so difficult. So how can I find the maximum value of the volume of the solid of revolution of $f$?

Comment: What is a "maximum value of [a] solid"?

Comment: Also this $f$ is only defined for positive $x$, which conflicts with the domain being $[-1,2]$.

Comment: Maybe the e-power has to be in the bottom and the x-term in the top?

Comment: @alex.jordan I don't know...